# PHP/JavaScript cookie acting like a pointer so when I clear it, I lose the value; how do I grab the value from the cookie?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var test = "test";
    document.cookie = "some_test=" + guid;
</script>

<?php $_POST['important_value'] = ((isset($_COOKIE['some_test'])) ? ($_COOKIE['some_test']) : ('')); ?>

<script>
    //document.cookie = "some_test=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;";
    console.log(document.cookie);
</script>
```

This code works exactly as intended so long as I don't uncomment the line to clear the cookie. The goal is to move the JavaScript variable (*test*) to the PHP variable (*$_POST['important_value']*).

I think what's happening is that *$_POST['important_value']* and *$_COOKIE['some_test']* are pointing to the same thing but I could be wrong. Is there anyway to print the address of the variables?

UPDATE:

```
debug_zval_dump($_POST['important_value']);
// string(39) "750118664537365903071115537365768136624" refcount(3)

debug_zval_dump($_COOKIE['some_test']);
// string(39) "750118664537365903071115537365768136624" refcount(3)
```

I'm assuming this means my assumption is correct? How do I get the string value from the cookie without the pointer?

Comment: I would not recommend setting values in the `$_POST` super global. They should only ever come from the request

Comment: So you want to pass something from javascript to php... is that what you're saying? If so then you should know php is executed on the server before the client-side (javascript) so that could cause an issue with your method of doing this. If you're trying to use `$_POST[]` are you actually sending/posting anything? If so how and where...

Comment: @Phil ok, I can change it to a plain variable.

Comment: @NewToJS That is what I'm saying, yes. Also, that's good to know, but it seems to work perfectly well regardless of order of execution... I have no trouble getting the JavaScript variable to PHP via the cookie, I can even echo the value of the cookie out on the screen during render.

Comment: @JohnCullen What do you mean without getting the address? Can you edit your question and explain what you are currently getting and then below it show the expected output. Thank you.

Comment: Your cookie is really visible only on the next visit, not in current one, see my explanation below :)

Comment: @NewToJS Thanks for your help. Mob helped me below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's understand how your code works:

1. Browser request the page yourpage.php. For the first run the cookie is empty, so on the server side your cookie is empty anycase.
2. Browser loads the page with your JS, actually for the first run it is equals:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     var test = "test";
     document.cookie = "some_test=" + guid;
   </script>

   <script>
       //document.cookie = "some_test=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;";
       console.log(document.cookie);
   </script>
   ```
3. Browser receiving the cookie from your JS
4. On the next visit your PHP code sees the cookie and you assign it to the POST variable, which finishes it's life after the page execution.
5. If you destroy the cookie (by uncomment your commented line), at 3rd step browser removes the cookie, so on 4th stage browser doesn't see your cookie :)

Comment: Oh, damn. Ok. I'm starting to see now. The stages example helped a lot. I think this is what Phil was trying to explain to me. I'll have to figure out a different way to do this then. I was trying to avoid an AJAX like solution but I think I'll have to move in that direction. Thank you so much for taking the time to explain.

Comment: Glad to help you! :)
If you need to send the POST request anywhere, you can do it for the few ways.
You can generate the form with hidden inputs on the PHP side and submit it with javascript (client-side request), or send POST request with CURL from PHP side (server-side request), or send it with Ajax.
It all depends on what you really need after getting the cookie :)